# Get json response to axios from laravel controlller

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

So I am making `axios` post request to Laravel controller:

```
 return axios.post('/create',
   {
     data: {...currentSettings},
   },
   {
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json'
   }}).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
   });
```

And Controller should return `json` response:

```
return response()->json([
     'data' => $data,
]);
```

But somehow in response I receive `text/html`
[image: ![enter image description here]

And also Response headers says this: 
[image]

Cant find solution to fix this.. Would appreciate some help

Comment: According to Laravel documentation, `json()` should set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#json-responses). Can you check the backend using postman to make sure if the problem is with laravel?

Comment: Checked with postman same result returns ```text/html```

Comment: What is the type of `$data`? If replacing the variable with an inline string solves the issue, then the problem might be for `$data` variable.

Comment: Nope, this variable is just a string ```'hello world'```. Trying everything :D

Comment: I have tested your code in my environment. It's working perfectly fine. Sharing the rest of your code(of those particular functions) may help people to find the issue.

Comment: Are you passing array in your $data variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to await for the response.json() and then console.log your data accordingly.

```
return axios.post('/create',
   {
     data: {...currentSettings},
   },
   {
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json'
   }}).then(async response => {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data. Data)
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at that:
You have double

```
data
```

Because your code:

```
return response()->json([
     'data' => $data,
]);
basic response of laravel has data and you and one data property => data.data
```

You don't need to add header when use axios
To get data from controller like this;

```
 console.log(response.data.data);
```